# VIsual Studio 2010. NuGet is installing fine but not responding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

I have installed NuGet on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. x64.

My OS is Windows 7 ultimate.

NuGet appears to be installing fine.

Here is a log of NuGet after it has installed.:

19-03-2012 13:35:24 - Microsoft Visual Studio Extension Installer 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 - ------------------------------------------- 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 - Initializing Install... 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 - Extension Details... 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Identifier      : NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Name            : NuGet Package Manager 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Author          : Microsoft Corporation 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Version         : 1.6.21215.9133 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Description     : A collection of tools to automate the process of downloading, installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing packages from a VS Project. 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Locale          : en-US 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     MoreInfoURL     : http://docs.nuget.org/ 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     InstalledByMSI  : False 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     MinFramework    : 4.0 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     MaxFramework    : 4.0 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -  
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Supported Visual Studio Editions :  
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -         Version : 10.0 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             Pro 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             IntegratedShell 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             VWDExpress 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             VPDExpress 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -         Version : 11.0 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             Pro 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             IntegratedShell 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             VWDExpress 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -             VPDExpress 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 - 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     Supported Isolated Shells : 
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -  
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -     References      :  
19-03-2012 13:35:24 -  
19-03-2012 13:35:24 - The extension with ID 'NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5' is not installed to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. 
19-03-2012 13:35:27 - The following target products have been selected... 
19-03-2012 13:35:27 -     Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate 
19-03-2012 13:35:27 -  
19-03-2012 13:35:27 - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate... 
19-03-2012 13:35:27 - Install to Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate completed successfully. The extension has been installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager\1.6.21215.9133\

But when I try starting opening the console manager for the NuGet, nothing appears and even no error message is displayed.

When I try to make a new ASP.NET MVC 3 type of project, then Visual Studio doesn't allow me to do it. And it shows an error:

> Nuget Package Manager is missing.

- I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling NuGet.
- I have already disabled all the other extensions that I was using.
- I have tried deleting the packages folder but no help.

NuGet was working the last time I checked.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Might be some problem with your priviledges. Have you tried running Visual Studio with Admin rights?

Comment: yes.. on my system.. i always run VS as an admin. i have change the compatibility setting. so that it always runs like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I don't know why this was happening... I did the following things.

1. Repaired Visual Studio 2010
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled ASP.NET MVC 3

And I could make an ASP.NET MVC 3 project again... :)